# testing an webapp

Tags: testing, web-applications, simulation

I've spent some time in learning CakePHP, by building some webapps. Now I need to test some of them, before I'll put them on a public place.

Can you give me some pointers about how can I simulate a real case environment in order to know which are the problems?

Comment: i suggest running a search on this site for testing a webapp.... there are so many questions about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, I recommend looking [HERE](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mariano/2007/04/13/testing-models-with-cakephp-1-2-test-suite).

[Software QA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality_assurance) (testing) is a big subject, and a professional discipline in it's own right; apart from coding. Furthermore, web QA is also a whole separate branch that (when done well) requires experience with understanding some technical aspects of Internet and browser technologies, especially as it relates to security -- which appears to be one of your concerns. As someone who used to work in QA, and worked with developing test automation, asking about a more specific issue might also get you an optimally useful answer.

To throw out a partial answer, I'll address the idea of [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). This is like the programmer approach to testing one piece of software at a time through the use of a "harness". As a fan, the nicest thing about Cake is the "framework" concept does make this kind of testing possible and [relatively simple](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mariano/2007/04/13/testing-models-with-cakephp-1-2-test-suite). As mentioned from that page, the idea is that fixtures allow you to define sample data sourced from a test connection when executing the script from test mode (within the harness).

In conclusion, I'd like to elaborate more about the framework idea and how it plays into software development. The real issue is that good software needs to be developed/architected with a set of methodologies that allow it to be require minimal maintenance, while maximizing reusability. The [top-down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design), tiered development approach is advisable so that each tier or level is testable. [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) (which Cake mostly implements) is a model for how code can be separated and each area can be tested independently, ostensibly allowing one to conclude that the system as a whole is functional, secure, etc. However, final, [black-box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing), outer-level, user-expereince testing is still required to assess how things work together. It isn't often that good developers make good testers (or want to be), besides which it's a great idea to enlist as many other sets of eyes as possible on your software. So, definitely allow lots of testing time into your release cycles if you plan on releasing a quality product that people will want to keep using.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to simulate a user interacting with your app through the browser.

Comment: I've had success with WAPT for Windows (http://www.loadtestingtool.com/), and it's fairly cheap. Also check out: http://browsermob.com